# Custom value to value map function

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, mapping

I have a view that I want to move based on a progress. The view contains labels with different widths. Everything is auto-generated.

Space between labels is set to: 48

Possibly the view will look like this (widths in parenthesis):

```
| Label1 (20) | 48 | Label2 (40) | 48 | Label3 (60) | 48 | Label4 (30) | 48 | Label5 (10) |
```

For this example, I want the results to be like:

- foo(0.0)  = 0.0   (Label1.frameMinX)
- foo(0.25) = 68.0  (Label2.frameMinX)
- foo(0.4)  = 120.8 (Label2.frameMinX -> Label3.frameMinX)
- foo(0.45) = 138.4 (Label2.frameMinX -> Label3.frameMinX)
- foo(0.5)  = 156.0 (Label3.frameMinX)
- foo(0.75) = 264.0 (Label4.frameMinX)
- foo(1.0)  = 342.0 (Label5.frameMinX)

So, how will `foo` look like?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for:

http://www.paulwrightapps.com/blog/2014/9/4/finding-the-position-and-angle-of-points-along-a-bezier-curve-on-ios